# Is searching for a German quote on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have a German quote in my mind I read some time ago.

I remember the meaning but neither words nor author. An extended Google search brought up various other quotes but not the quote I am looking for.

**Is a question searching for the quote on-topic?**

As requested in the comment the question I have in my mind:

> I am searching for a German quote I read some time time ago.
>
> Here is what I remember:
>
> - It is about politics
> - The general meaning was something like this: Don't adopt the opinion/beliefs of the public. Instead make your opinion/beliefs popular.
> - Length was about 2-3 sentences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotes, aphorisms and idioms are on-topic in my opinion.

Whether such a question turns out to be good or bad then, depends on the normal quality issues we would have with that question (amount of hints, uniqueness of hints,...). The danger is: If you can't remember the quote, the hints are likely not to be very good.

Answer (score 3):

I would say: Yes, it is on-topic.